# Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I have some algorithms that I am trying to find the time complexity for. I came up with some answers but I am not certain if they are right or not. Can someone help me out?

```
public static int f4(int N){
   if (N == 0) return 0;
   return f4(N/2) + f1(N) + f4(N/2);
} // f1 had a time complexity of O(n)
```

1) I believe this one is O(n).

```
public static find f6(int N){
   if (N == 0) return 1;
   return f6(N-1) + f6(N-1);
}
```

2) I believe this is O(n!) or O(n).

Comment: What is `f1`? Can't evaluate `f4` without knowing it.

Comment: I'm not sure a direct answer to this question is really what the asker needs, rather than a complete course in algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @ ShadowRanger OP said "f1" had a time complexity of o(n)

Comment: @Lotharyx Algorithm analysis is my next course. This problem is for data structures.

Comment: `public`: did you mean to use the java tag instead of c++? The answer depends if your compiler is clever enough to evaluate `f6(N-1)` only once (and multiply it by 2), it might even be optimized to `1<<N` for `O(1)` running time... Still, taking a guess at what you really want, all of your guesses are wrong.

Comment: 1) O(n logn). See master theorem. Example: merge sort. 2) O(2^n). Draw a binary tree. The base of it has 2^n nodes, total nodes is 2*2^n - 1 => O(2^n)

Answer (score 1):

### Analysis of The First Problem

The [master theorem](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf) states that, given a recurrence of the form `f(n) = a*f(n/b) + O(n^k)`, three types of complexity may result:

1. The time complexity is `O(n^k)` if `log_{b}(a) < k`
2. The time complexity is `O(n^k log n)` if `log_{b}(a) == k`
3. The time complexity is `O(n^(log_{b}(a))` if `log_{b}(a) == k`

The first recurrence takes the form:

```
f4(N) = 2f4(N/2) + O(n) = 2f4(N/2) + O(n^1)
```

This clearly falls into the second case, as `log_{2}(2) == 1`. The correct answer is therefore `O(n log n)`.

Your first problem has **polylogarithmic** time complexity.

### Analysis of The Second Problem

The recurrence takes the form

```
f6(N) = 2f6(N - 1)
```

which you can expand as follows:

```
f6(N) = (2^k)f6(N - k)
```

by simply applying the relationship to `f6(N-1)`, `f6(N-2)`, etc.

Since `f6(0)` returns instantly i.e. it takes 1 step to return, the full runtime complexity is

```
f6(N) = 2^N
```

just by plugging in `k == N`.

Thus, the second problem has **exponential time complexity**.

Answer (score 0):

I Think is better solve this problem recursively just like the calling method does.
for function f6 :

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + c      = > T(n-1) = 2T(n-2) + c
Then : T(n) = 2(2T(n-2)) + c) + c 
T(n) = 4T(n-2) + 2c + c      => T(n-2) = 2T(n-3) + c
T(n) = 4(2(T(n-3) + c) + 2c + c 
T(n) = 8T(n-3) + 4c + 2c + c
.
.
.
T(n) = 2^i T(n - i) + 2^(i-1)c + 2^(i-2)c + ... + (2^0)c
When i asymptotically goes to n , that is : i => n , then : 
T(n) = 2^n T(n-n) + 2^(n-1)c + 2^(n-2)c + ... + (2^0)c
T(n) = O(2^n)
```

Answer (score -1):

The Akshat answer is in detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43880977/6866309

The second function will become O(n!), if it has a loop inside the function.

Something like below example is O(n!).

```
f6(int N){
   if (N == 0) return 1;

   for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      f6(N-1) + f6(N-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: You analysis for 1 is incorrect. You are forgetting the [master theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Master_theorem) - the recurrence relation for `f4` is `f4(N) = 2f4(N/2) + O(n)`, which correctly resolves to `O(n log n`).

Comment: You are correct in one way..... But in that  function ..... a O(n) function is called "N" number of times....

Comment: Nice catch, but in that case the recurrence relation becomes `f4(N) = 2f4(N/2) + n*(O(n))`, which is of the same order as `f4(N) = 2f4(N/2) + O(n^2)`, meaning it is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Actually, no. The `O(n)` function is not being called `n` times. It is being called once for `n`. It will be called in a recursive call for `O(n/2)`, but you can still demonstrate that that will have an overall complexity of `O(n)` by drawing the associated binary tree.

Comment: @kataymaradu: You are trying to replace the term in the recurrence relation with the *full* runtime complexity of the function in terms of its base cases *without* taking into account the effect on `f4(N/2)` (which calls an O(n/2) function, and so on). The master theorem lets you calculate the runtime complexity using just the runtime complexity of the return signature, which is correctly just `2f4(N/2) + O(n)`. Please consult the proof of the master theorem to understand how to substitute it correctly, it's in the link.

Comment: You can link to other answers by using the share link below it. Then you don't look silly by saying things like "above answer" when your answer is above the other.

Comment: Thanks. I never noticed it. Thanks.